# In the rank nullity theorem for $T \colon V \to W$, $V$ is finite dimensional. What if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra

> In the Sylvester rank nullity theorem, $T \colon V \to W$ is a linear transformation and $V$ is finite dimensional. What if $V$ is infinite dimensional?

This was actually asked before on this site, but I’m not satisfied with the answers. Please give me a sketch of a proof how this is true in infinite dimensions, and please give me an example for it.

Comment: I've seen all stack querries, if you have your own please share in answer box rather comment

Comment: @PriyaDey it may help your question if you go through some of the other answers to this question and explain what you found unsatisfying or difficult to understand.